# Escaping problem of "\n" and " ' " while using LXML in python

Tags: python, xml, escaping, lxml, special-characters

I'm trying to use LXML to process a string in a XML file. The problem is the output file unable to escape some of the special characters(e.g. "\n" and " ' "). Here is the text I need to process with:

input text:

```
IF [Calculation_1] = 'Day-1' THEN [begintime] + 1
ELSEIF[Calculation_1] < 'Day-2' THEN [begintime] + 2
ELSEIF  [Calculation_1] > "Day-3" THEN [begintime] + 3
ELSE [begintime]
END
```

actual output text:

```
IF [Calculation_1] = 'Day-1' THEN [begintime] + 1
ELSEIF[Calculation_1] &lt; 'Day-2' THEN [begintime] + 2
ELSEIF  [Calculation_1] &gt; &quot;Day-3&quot; THEN [begintime] + 3
ELSE [begintime]
END
```

expected output text:

```
IF [Calculation_1] = &apos;Day-1&apos; THEN [begintime] + 1&#10;ELSEIF[Calculation_1] &lt; &apos;Day-2&apos; THEN [begintime] + 2&#10;ELSEIF  [Calculation_1] &gt; &quot;Day-3&quot; THEN [begintime] + 3&#10;ELSE [begintime]&#10;END
```

My python scripts:

```
from lxml import etree as ET

Name_with_single_quote= """IF [Calculation_1] = 'Day-1' THEN [begintime] + 1
ELSEIF[Calculation_1] < 'Day-2' THEN [begintime] + 2
ELSEIF  [Calculation_1] > "Day-3" THEN [begintime] + 3
ELSE [begintime]
END"""

Name_with_single_quote = Name_with_single_quote.replace("\n", "&#10;").replace("<", "&lt;").replace("'", "&apos;").replace(">","&gt;").replace("\"", "&quot;")
Name_with_single_quote = str(Name_with_single_quote)

xml = """<?xml version="1.0"?>
<column role="dimension" type="nominal" name="[Calculation_1]" datatype="boolean" caption="">
<calculation formula=""/>
</column>"""

tree = ET.fromstring(xml)
formula = tree.find('.//calculation')
formula.set('formula', Name_with_single_quote)

from xml.dom import minidom
xmlstr = minidom.parseString(ET.tostring(tree)).toprettyxml()
xmlstr = '\n'.join(list(filter(lambda x: len(x.strip()), xmlstr.split('\n'))))
with open('test_for_esc_result.xml', "w") as f:
    f.write(xmlstr)
```

Does anyone know how to escape those special characters?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: So you want `\n` to be represented as `&#10;` and `'` to be represented as `&quot;`? Is that what you mean by "process a string"?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to replace  "\n" and " ' " into &#10; and &apos;.

Comment: @mzjn I've updated the python scripts in the question. Thank you so much!